# Shared data class using std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I need a class that implements shared data semantics, and probably `std::shared_ptr` is a good place to start. I think a typical implementation of such class could use an private `shared_ptr` to the shared data, and then implement at least copy constructor and `operator=`.

Something like:

```
class SharedDataClass {

public:
  SharedDataClass(const SharedDataClass& other)
  {
    data_ = other.data_;
  };

  SharedDataClass& operator=(const SharedDataClass& other)
  {
    data_ = other.data_;
    return *this;
  }

private:
  std::shared_ptr<DataType> data_;
};
```

I'd like to ask if anyone has some criticism to offer on the above implementation. Is there any other member/operator that should be implemented for consistency?

Comment: `= default;` seems enough

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<DataType> data` takes care of all this for you.

Comment: And there is also the move constructor/assignment.

Comment: Ok, so it seems that there is no particular warning flag to be raised as to the logic of the implementation, except for noting that `default` is all you really need in this case. I guess c++11 is succeeding in making things easier at last...

Comment: This belongs on Code Review.

Comment: @KerrekSB this really looks like example code rather than real, working code, that would be off-topic on Code Review if that is the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to implement a copy constructor or an assignment operator in this case. Let the compiler defines the trivial default ones for you, the shared_ptr will do the job you are expecting.

Comment: That's a good point, thanks. However this is more a way to obtain what I already have with less effort.

Answer (score 1):

I see one minor pitfall. Typically the default constructor should not be defaulted, as it will create a null `data_` pointer. I think in general it is more desirable to have the default constructor to create a `data_` pointer holding a default-constructed `DataType` object.